# Ajax.Updater insertion not working in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, internet-explorer-9

I have the following piece of code being automatically created by a Ruby on Rails function call.  It works great in Firefox and Chrome, as well as IE8, but does not work in IE9.

```
<form 
 action="/cms/quiz_questions/auto_populate" 
 id="auto_pop_questions_form" 
 method="post" 
 onsubmit="new Ajax.Updater(
   'quiz_questions', 
   '/cms/quiz_questions/auto_populate', 
   {
     asynchronous:true, 
     evalScripts:true, 
     insertion:'after', 
     onComplete:function(request){
       toggle_hidden(&quot;search_comp&quot;, false);
       update_existing_questions(); 
     }, 
     parameters:Form.serialize(this)
   }
 ); 
 return false;">
```

If I remove the insertion parameter, then it works fine in IE9, but then my content gets replaced instead of added to. Why doesn't this work correctly in IE9?  Or, alternatively, how can I do this AJAX call in a different way to avoid the issue?

Comment: Maybe try **insertion: Insertion.After** instead of **insertion:'after'**. The Insertion object notation is deprecated, but since Internet Explorer is a little slow, it might work. Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  That might work, I'm not sure.  But since this is automatically created by Ruby on Rails, it's not an option.  Turns out I needed to upgrade my version of Prototype.  Thanks for trying, though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to upgrade my version of Prototype. I was running Prototype 1.6.0.1, and just an upgrade to 1.6.0.2 fixed the issue.  Further upgrades would probably work as well.